# Elasticsearch substring must be contained in field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elastic-stack

I have the following query:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "match" : {  "log": "a perfect phrase" }
      },
     "filter": 
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
               "gte": "now-10m",
               "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I sometimes get documents that contains some of the words from `a perfect phrase` but that are NOT exactly `a perfect phrase`. I would like to only keep document that contains this exact string, not documents that contains *pretty much* this string.

Since this string is usually contained in much larger document that can contain random data, I do not think that I can use the `term` keyword.

How can I look for all documents which `log` field contain exactly this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match_phrase` instead of `match`.

So basically your search query would be as follows:

```
GET your-index-name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "match_phrase" : {  "log": "a perfect phrase" }
      },
     "filter": 
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
               "gte": "now-10m",
               "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Refer to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) for more information on it.